# Checkbox Toggle button: Heredar propiedad Checked a una imagen

Tags: delphi

Estoy haciendo un toggle switch, que cuando le de clic cambie de estado `On/off`, logré hacerlo haciendo `override` del método `Paint` en `TCanvas`, todo bien pero los bordes se veían pixelados.

Así que mejor modifiqué el componente para cargar una imagen para cada estado dependiendo del checked de la imagen, en resumen estoy poniendo un componente `TImage` dentro de un `Checkbox` heredado de `TwwCheckbox` pero al cargarle la imagen de alguna manera cuando estoy asignando el `DataSet` no lo pone en estado de edición al darle `checked`, al parecer la imagen ya no esta heredando las propiedades que disparan el `Checked`

Porque cuando le quito la imagen y dibujo un canvas, si lo hace correctamente pero cuando esta la imagen no, y me sale el siguiente error:

`qryToggleButton: Dataset not in edit or insert mode`

```
{aqui creo el toggle en runtime y le asigno un datasource 
para conectarlo a la base de datos}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ToggleButton:= TinToggleButton2.Create(Self);
   ToggleButton.Name := 'ToggleButton';
   ToggleButton.Parent:= Self;
   ToggleButton.Left:= 200;
   ToggleButton.Top:=100;
   ToggleButton.Visible:= true;
   ToggleButton.ValueChecked:= 'S';
   ToggleButton.ValueUnchecked:= 'N';
   ToggleButton.DisplayValueChecked:= 'S';
   ToggleButton.DisplayValueUnchecked:= 'N';
   ToggleButton.DataField:= 'TAutoSave';
   ToggleButton.DataSource:= dsToggleButton;
   ToggleButton.DataSource.DataSet:= qryToggleButton;
end;

//activo el query 
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   qryToggleButton.Active:= true;
end;

//mando a la base de datos
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qryToggleButton.Post;
end;


{aquí creo el componente en otra unidad donde esta el evento click 
para cambiar entre imagen}
constructor TinToggleButton2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
   inherited;
   Width:= 34;
   Height:= 15;
   Image:= TImage.Create(Self);
   Image.Visible:= true;
   Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('toggle_Toggle1.ico');
   Image.Parent:= Self;
   Image.OnClick:=Self.Image1Click;
   Self.Checked:= false;
   Checked:= false;
end;

procedure TinToggleButton2.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Image.Enabled then
    begin
      if Self.Checked then
      begin
         Self.Checked:= false;
         Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('toggle_Toggle1.ico');
      end
  else
    begin
      Self.Checked:= true;
      Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('toggle_Toggle2.ico');
    end
  end;
 end;
```

El `toggle` lo creo en runtime pero los otros componentes como el `TwwDataSource` y el `TADOQuery` los pongo en la forma y al checkbox le asigno tanto el `DataField` como el `DataSource` pero no se si me falta hacerle `override` a otra propiedad para que se active el `Checked` del componente cada vez que le hago `Checked` a la imagen, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Lo suyo sería ejecutar paso a paso a ver en qué punto (línea del programa) te está dando el error.

De todas formas, según el error, lo más seguro es que se produzca cuando cambias el valor del CheckBox. Eso debe lanzar la modificación del campo asociado y eso debe provocar el error del Dataset.

Antes de modificar el check, deberías comprobar si en dataset está en edición y si no lo está, ponerlo en ese modo.

Te lo pongo de memoria, pero la idea es esta:

```
if Assigned(Self.Dataset) then
  if not (Self.Dataset.State in dsEditModes) then
    Self.Dataset.Edit;
Self.Checked := true;
...
```

Comment: De hecho lo que hice fue evaluar si el `datasource` era diferente de `nil`, si si era poner `DataSource.Edit` directamente y por cada `Checked` poner su `Dataset.FieldByName` con su `ValueChecked` y `ValueUnchecked` correspondiente

Comment: Deberías añadir esas comprobaciones en el procedimiento:  TinToggleButton2.Image1Click